# From a string I am manually setting the date and time in calendar, for the other days it is working fine but for 28 and 29 Feb it is setting wrong val

Tags: java, spring, date, time, java-8

```
String req  ="0229191315"

private static DateFormat dateFrmtGmt - new SimpleDateFormat ("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);


SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat( "MMddHHmmss");

cal.setTime(sdf.parse(gmtDate));
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));

dateFrmtGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

return cal;
```

`String = "0229191315"` returns Fri Mar 1 19:13:15 GMT 2024

While `string="0301191315"` returns Fri 1 mar 19:13:15 GMT 2024

For all the dates it is setting correct date and time but for 28 and 29 Jan 2024 settings value as 29 Feb and 1 March respectively .

Comment: You are setting Februari not januari. I would also strongly suggest against using `SimpleDateFormat` **and** `Calendar` classes. Those should be avoided and use the new Date & Time classes instead.

Comment: This shows but a very little bit of the confusion that 10 years ago existed with `Calendar`. That class and `TimeZone` had severe design problems, and `SimpleDateFormat` was still worse. This month they have been supplanted by java.time 10 years ago, and I see no reason why anyone should ever want to use them.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are parsing the input without a year. Looking at the documentation of the [SimpleDateFormat.parse() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.text.ParsePosition-).

> the year value of the parsed Date is 1970 with GregorianCalendar if no year value is given from the parsing operation.

Since year 1970 didn't had a February 29 date the parse returned March 1. After that you set the actual year but the date remains as it was parsed.

See a modern approach to resolve this issue using the java.time package in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44470949/721855

Answer (score 3):

[Per @Anonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78180423/from-a-string-i-am-manually-setting-the-date-and-time-in-calendar-for-the-other#comment137829162_78180423): Use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and `OffsetDateTime`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). Don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Calendar` and `TimeZone` since they had severe design problems and have been outdated the last 10 years.

Define a constant `PARSER` as:

```java
private static final DateTimeFormatter PARSER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("MMddHHmmss")
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, Year.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).getValue())
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)
        .toFormatter();
```

Or depending on exact requirements you may need to instantiate the parser for each use so you always get the current year, not the year when the parser was created.

Offsets are from GMT or UTC. We can regard GMT and UTC as the same thing for now. So defaulting offset in seconds to 0 means defaulting to UTC, which gives you the GMT time as in your question.

Then parse into an `OffsetDateTime` using:

```java
OffsetDateTime d = OffsetDateTime.parse(req, PARSER);
```

This yields **2024-02-29T19:13:15Z**. The trailing `Z` denotes UTC.